# How can i refactor these two methods

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, refactoring

hi i have two methods like and three more methods (not mention in this question) ..

how can i refactor these ones ..

**Method 1** :

```
   public  DataTable GetVisits(System.DateTime startdate , System.DateTime enddate)
     { 


         const string sql  = @"SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(visit_Status, 1, 1)), SUBSTRING(visit_Status FROM 2))  as Status, COUNT('x') AS Visits
                              FROM visits
                              WHERE visit_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                              GROUP BY visit_Status";

         var tblvisits = new DataTable();

         using (var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
         {
             conn.Open();

             var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, conn);


             var ds = new DataSet();

             var parameter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@startdate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter.Value = startdate.ToString(dateformat);
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

             var parameter2 = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@enddate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter2.Value = enddate.ToString(dateformat);
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

             var da = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

             da.Fill(ds);
             try
             {
                 tblvisits = ds.Tables[0];

             }
             catch
             {
                tblvisits = null;

             }

         }
         return tblvisits;
     }
```

**method 2 :**  :

```
       public DataTable sales(System.DateTime startdate, System.DateTime enddate)
       {
         const string sql = @"SELECT memberAccTran_Source as Category, sum(memberAccTran_Value) as Value
                              FROM memberacctrans
                              WHERE memberAccTran_DateTime BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                              GROUP BY memberAccTran_Source";

         var memacctvalues = new DataTable();
         using (var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
         {
             conn.Open();

             var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

             var ds = new DataSet();

             var parameter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@startdate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter.Value = startdate.ToString(dateformat);
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

             var parameter2 = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@enddate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter2.Value = enddate.ToString(dateformat);
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

             var da = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

             da.Fill(ds);
             try
             {
                 memacctvalues = ds.Tables[0];

             }
             catch
             {
                 memacctvalues = null;
             }
         }
         return memacctvalues;         
     }
```

would any one have any idea how can i refactor these two methods

> (
>
> > i have three methods more like this but only difference is sql query
> >     )

Comment: what is the reason why you feel like you need to refactor them. And what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the only difference between all the flavors of the method is the SQL code, then create a public method for each one, and have all of them call a private method that has the common code, passing in the correct sql string.

```
private DataTable PerformQuery(string sql, System.DateTime startdate, System.DateTime enddate)
 { 
     var tblvisits = new DataTable();

     using (var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
     {
         conn.Open();

         var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, conn);


         var ds = new DataSet();

         var parameter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@startdate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
         parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
         parameter.Value = startdate.ToString(dateformat);
         cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

         var parameter2 = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@enddate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
         parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
         parameter2.Value = enddate.ToString(dateformat);
         cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

         var da = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

         da.Fill(ds);
         try
         {
             tblvisits = ds.Tables[0];

         }
         catch
         {
            tblvisits = null;

         }

     }
     return tblvisits;
 }
```

And then for the public ones:

```
   public DataTable Sales(System.DateTime startdate, System.DateTime enddate)
   {
     const string sql = @"SELECT memberAccTran_Source as Category, sum(memberAccTran_Value) as Value
                          FROM memberacctrans
                          WHERE memberAccTran_DateTime BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                          GROUP BY memberAccTran_Source";

      return PerformQuery(sql, startdate, enddate);
   }



     public  DataTable GetVisits(System.DateTime startdate , System.DateTime enddate)
     { 
         const string sql  = @"SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(visit_Status, 1, 1)), SUBSTRING(visit_Status FROM 2))  as Status, COUNT('x') AS Visits
                              FROM visits
                              WHERE visit_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                              GROUP BY visit_Status";
          return PerformQuery(sql, startdate, enddate);
       }
```

And repeat for each of the others.  This is assuming, as you seemed to indicate, that all the parameters are the same, and the only difference is the SQL being run.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the SQL queries outside the method and pass it as a parameter.